# Google Search Console: Is it possible to exclude certain domains from domain property?

Tags: google-search-console, multi-subdomains

I've added a domain property in Google Search Console. As a result, the following domains/subdomains are now being monitored by GSC:

- `example.com`
- `red.example.com`
- `green.example.com`
- `blue.example.com`
- `orange.example.com`
- `purple.example.com`

I would like to exclude a couple of subdomains (such as `green.example.com` and `blue.example.com`) from my domain property as these subdomains are linked to another server and only presents a login page. I would still like these pages to be indexed by Google but just don't want them monitored by GSC and notifying me all sorts of mobile usability issues. Is it possible to exclude these specific subdomains?

Answer (score 4):

### Unfortunately, no. That is not possible.

I would very much like to provide a more detailed answer here, but it's really just that straight forward.

We get 2 options:

[image: domain property vs url prefix property google search console]

Why don't you just create an email folder and filter your emails from `sc-noreply@google.com` ?

You *could* create just url-prefix properties for the domains you care about...but then you might miss critical notifications.

I think you should just address your mobile usability issues...

Problem solved ; )

Comment: Regarding "You could create just url-prefix properties for the domains you care about" in other words, use the right option "URL Prefix" to monitor https://example.com (and  optionally a second one on https://www.example.com if needed)? I'm running into a similar issue where I have https://myworkdomain.com and search console is finding that and another customer specific instance of https://mycustomer.myworkdomain.com that I want to omit. What are the downsides of this if I only have two prefixes that I want to monitor? i.e. You mention missing "critical notifications". Thanks.